# Magento 2 : Cachable:false issues

Tags: magento2, blocks, full-page-cache

I need to make my minicart not include in Magento's FPC. 
So, I've added below code to my layout's default.xml file.

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.header" template="Magento_Theme::html/header.phtml" cacheable="false">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="target" xsi:type="string">contentarea</argument>
                        <argument name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Skip to Content</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
```

But, The problem is now header is included in all pages of website, And its make website slower, Like we have disabled cache from admin.

I've seen many questions regarding not to use **cacheable="false"**.

Is there is any solution to make it possible ??

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **cacheable="false"** will make your whole page uncacheable. See devDocs [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching.html). You can extend the block, add this to it's constructor :

```
protected function _construct()
{
     $this->addData(array(
        'cache_lifetime' => 0
     );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `cacheable=false` for the following block.

```
<block type="checkout/cart_minicart" name="minicart_head" template="checkout/cart/minicart.phtml" before="-">
```